# Printing matrix table from MySQL with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, matrix, pdo

I have three tables `countries`, `product_categories` and `vats` including following information

**product_categories**
includes two columns `product_category_code` and `product_category_name_en`

**countries**
[image: table: countries]

**vats**
[image: table: vats]

and one view `vats_view` which contains following query

```sql
SELECT 
    countries.country_code,
    product_categories.product_category_code,
    product_categories.product_category_name_en,
    vats.vat,
    vats.editedBy,
    vats.editedTimestamp
FROM
    vats,
    countries,
    product_categories
WHERE
    countries.country_code = vats.country
    AND product_categories.product_category_code = vats.product_category
```

---

I'd like to create a HTML matrix table based on this information. In this case the table would look like

```
---------------------------------------------------
|             |   AL   |   DE   |   DK   |   SE   |
---------------------------------------------------
| Category 10 | 14.00  |        |        | 10.00  |
| Category 20 | 15.00  |        |        |        |
| Category 30 |        |        |        |        |
---------------------------------------------------
```

I have done following code. I know that it's totally wrong and not working yet, but I'm asking for ideas about how to do this.

```php
echo "<table class=\"table table-bordered\"><tr><th></th>";
    $sql = $pdo->query("SELECT country_code FROM countries WHERE active = 1 ORDER BY country_code ASC");

    while($country = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<th class=\"text-center\">".$country['country_code']."</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    $sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM product_categories");

    while($vat = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$vat['product_category_name_'.$lang]."</td>";
        $sqlvats= $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM vats_view WHERE product_category_code = '".$vat['product_category_code']."'");

        while($row = $sqlvats->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<td>".$row['vat']."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
     }
     echo "</table>";
```

Any ideas are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The logic seems correct, except for the second query using $sql instead of $vat ¿can you expand why your code is not working?

Comment: @PerroVerd, it's not working correctly because it can't handle empty fields. So the values of `vat` is printed starting from the first `td`. So in this example the Sweden's value (SE, 10.00) is set to the Germany's position (DE).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I fixed the second query to use the proper $vat variable, replaced the third query with prepared statements (just a good practice) and replaced the while with an if to take care of empty results

```
echo "<table class=\"table table-bordered\"><tr><th></th>";
$sql = $pdo->query("SELECT country_code FROM countries WHERE active = 1 ORDER BY country_code ASC");

while($country = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<th class=\"text-center\">".$country['country_code']."</th>";
}
echo "</tr>";
$vat = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM product_categories");

while($vat = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$vat['product_category_name_'.$lang]."</td>";
    $sqlvats = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM vats_view WHERE product_category_code = ?");
    $sqlvats->bindParam(1, $vat['product_category_code']);
    $sqlvats->execute();

    if ($row = $sqlvats->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<td>".$row['vat']."</td>";
    } else {
        echo "<td></td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Problem is that if I don't have anything information in some row there should be a blank cell. Now the code prints only one column and countries in header and vats in the cells don't match each other.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way would probably be

```
SELECT
  *
FROM 
  (SELECT
    countries.country_code,
    V1.vat,
    V1.product_category_name_en product
  FROM 
    (SELECT 
      product_categories.product_category_name_en,
      vats.vat,
      vats.country
    FROM vats
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN product_categories
      ON vats.product_category = product_categories.product_category_code
    ) V1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN countries
    ON countries.country_code = V1.country
  )
PIVOT
  (MAX(vat) FOR country_code IN ('AL' AL, 'DE' DE, 'DK' DK, 'SE' SE))
ORDER BY product
;
```

But that's unfortunately not MySQL compatible - works for Oracle: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e13ea/1).

However, following this path:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V1 AS
  SELECT 
    product_categories.product_category_name_en,
    vats.vat,
    vats.country
  FROM vats
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN product_categories
    ON vats.product_category = product_categories.product_category_code
;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V2 AS
  SELECT
    V1.product_category_name_en product,
    countries.country_code,
    V1.vat
  FROM V1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN countries
    ON countries.country_code = V1.country
;
```

... and using a `PIVOT` 'substitute':

```
SELECT
  product,
  MAX(CASE WHEN country_code = 'AL' THEN vat END) AL,
  MAX(CASE WHEN country_code = 'DE' THEN vat END) DE,
  MAX(CASE WHEN country_code = 'DK' THEN vat END) DK,
  MAX(CASE WHEN country_code = 'SE' THEN vat END) SE
FROM V2
GROUP BY product
ORDER BY product
;
```

... we can get the asked for

```
|     product |     AL |     DE |     DK |     SE |
|-------------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| Category 10 |     14 | (null) | (null) |     10 |
| Category 20 |     15 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| Category 30 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b17d/1).

You might want to encapsulate the last `SELECT` in another view to leave the data handling to the database, and to keep your code nice and tidy...

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.